# SSIS - How to take a specific cell in Excel and add it to a existing table as it's own column for every row

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have a SSIS package which takes one sheet of a Excel file and creates a SQL table from it. This is simple because it's in tabular form and SSIS takes care of it.

However, I have another sheet in that Excel file which has a specific cell with a dollar value in it, I would like to take that specific cells value and tack it onto the table created from the tabular data I mentioned above. Aka/ I want to add a column to the table created above, named InsuranceTotal2018, and fill every row in the table with the same value which is derived from that specific cells value.

Is this possible in SSIS? If so, how would one go about doing such?

Comment: You'd create a variable to hold the value. Then you could use an `Execute SQL Task` using your Excel connection manager to create a query to get the value from the cell you're interested in. Then in your main data flow, add a `Derived Column` transformation to add a new column using your variable.

Comment: Thanks @digital.aaron!! That guidance was enough to get me to a solution. Thank you so very much for your guidance.